# Play 2.0 framework - persistent threads for the main app cycle?

Tags: multithreading, scala, playframework-2.0

I am learnig the Play 2.0 framework for Scala and aside from being able to process requests, I would like to run a continuous task in the background, like a bunch of timers. And somehow be able to get access to those timers from the request-response actions without getting any thread synchronization problems. I have heard of Jobs in Play and there are Actors in Scala. However, I cannot find any info on Jobs in 2.0, they seem to have been replaced by Promises.. but really all this is not like running a persistent background thread, and I am not sure how Actors fit in the whole paradigm.

Basically, my question is - what is the traditional way to get this kind of persistance in Play 2.0.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not quite right, the Jobs have not been replaced by Promises, but by [scheduling to send messages to actors](http://www.playframework.org/documentation/2.0/ScalaAkka) (see "Scheduling asynchronous tasks").

Anyway, actors seem to be the way to go for you. Play 2.0 uses [Akka](http://akka.io/) for that. It's quite simple, actually. The Akka home page has detailed explanation on what Actors are and what you can do with them, but you can just think of an Actor as some code (say, a function) with a mailbox. You can send messages to the mailbox, and the function will be run for each message that is waiting for it. This could be just a periodical signal for a recurring job, or a reference for a long background task telling it what it needs to update.

Comment: Ok, I have read the Play tutorial on Actors and scheduling. The concept of Actors seems simple and logical to me, I also have some minor experience with them in Erlang, so everything seems clear to me except for one thing. What is the preferred way to organize the thread update cycle? Do I have to simply schedule a regular update impulse to the Actor that represents the thread, using the scheduler? Or do I start a Thread from an Actor and organize the cycle in it's `run()` method?

Comment: No need for extra threads, if you want to schedule a job to run e.g. every 30 minutes, just call `Akka.system.scheduler.schedule(0 seconds, 30 minutes, testActor, "tick")` and it will do it. If you need an event-based update job (e.g. resizing an image for later use after a user uploads it), send a message to the actor when the job has to be done: `myActor ! myMessage`.